# compiler can't find "aligned_alloc" function

Tags: c++, c

Trying to get a portable function to allocate on heap with aligned feature.

Found "aligned_alloc", which I think is in stdlib.h but gcc seems to not think so

> error: 'aligned_alloc' was not declared in this scope

using gcc with flags -std=c++11 -m64

tried importing

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with C++. It is C11 function, please make appropriate tag(s)

Comment: You might want to add `-std=c11` flag and see if function is here

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I do that and get this " warning: command line option '-std=c11' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++", also it does not solve issue

Comment: you have to make a decision.  Is this C code or C++ code.  your post includes both C '#include <stdlib.h>' and c++ '#include <cstdlib>'  which language are you wanting to use?  The '-std=c11' is only for C code.  Note that in C, malloc (and family) return a pointer to memory that is (for 32bit architecture) aligned on a 32bit boundary and (for 64bit architecture) aligned on a 64bit boundary.  So the function your looking for 'should' have no effect

Comment: Try `-std=gnu++11`.  Using `-std=c++11`, while it enables C++11 features (obviously), also disables a large number of gnu-specific features and functions which are enabled by default.  `gnu++11` is the right mode to have all the default stuff, plus C++11.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`aligned_alloc` is defined in C11. It is not (yet) defined for C++, although it may show up in C++17. (That is, it is not in the list of (currently) 209 functions in the standard C library which are expected to be available in the standard C++ library. See Appendix C of the C++ standard.)

(**Update August 2018**: `aligned_alloc` is indeed defined by C++17, as predicted above. So you if you have a sufficiently recent C++ compiler, you should be able to avoid all the messing around with feature-test macros by just specifying the use of C++17; for `g++` and `clang++`, that can be done with the `-std=c++17` command-line flag.)

If you want to use it with GCC (or, more specifically, with g++), you should use the feature test macro `_ISOC11_SOURCE`. Like all feature test macros, this macro must be `#define`'d in every file which requires it before any `#include`. [See note 1] (The feature test macro would not be necessary if you were compiling a C program with `-std=c11`.)

I found the correct feature test macro from `man aligned_alloc`:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>   posix_memalign(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600
>
>   aligned_alloc(): _ISOC11_SOURCE
> ```

As that indicates, you can read

```
man 7 feature_test_macros
```

for more information on feature test macros, including a list of the macros recognized by glibc, and when each one applies.

The `aligned_alloc` manpage also documents the very similar `posix_memalign` function, which has been part of the Posix standard since Issue 6, and which has different (and more common) feature test macros, as indicated above. `posix_memalign` should be portable to any Posix system, which might or might not include more systems than those that accept the use of a C11 function in C++.

### Notes

1. This means you shouldn't put the `#define` in a header file, since the header file cannot be included before the first include :) However, if you use something like `#include "config.h"` to include platform definitions, and every source file starts with `#include "config.h"`, prior to any other `#include`, and the `#define` occurs in `config.h` prior to any `#include`, you should be OK.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: It's not in C++14 either (I assume you meant `-std=c++14`, since `-std=c14` throws an error). However, it is in C++17, as I predicted in 2015. I've updated the answer to reflect that fact.

Comment: @nik-lz: the code sample on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) has "run this code" button which compiles and runs the code on coliru with g++ 7.1 invoked with --std=c++17. It demonstrably works, so g++ 7.1 is comformant, at least as far as `aligned_alloc` is concerned. If it doesn't work on your installation, it may be because you have an outdated compiler or because you are using a non-standard compliant library. In any case, a SO comment thread is really not an appropriate forum for compiler bug reports.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following on GNU linux with glibc

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <cstdlib>
```

Note that defining the macro was pulled from the header file source.

Comment: `incompatible redefinition of macro "_GNU_SOURCE"` . Same for `_IOSC11_SOURCE` with Intel compiler.

Comment: @marklanata: you have to define feature-test macros before any library header is included.